# How to get a small div bar to slide down a menu on mouseover

Tags: css, html, menu, slider

I want a simple slide-down div-bar like on soundcloud, youtube, gmail

It is used in some really good websites with a menu dropdown, and I want to know how to do it using css or even jquery if needed. I can't post images yet, because i don't have enough reputaion yet... [Here is the example on soundcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0VRQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DAxZA/)**, it should help you for sure.

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul id="nav-primary">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>

            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">beans</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">pork chop</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
</nav>
```

The css part is in the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DAxZA/)**

Comment: Thanks. This is a great menu, but not really what I was looking for. Maybe I should have been more specific on my question. What I really wanted to know how to do was to get the orange little thing on the left side of the example to slide down on mouseover.

Comment: Yes, maybe that is another question you need to ask. My answer does answer to YOUR question

Comment: Ok, thank you, I guess I'll have to ask a different question.